# Error trying to restore NUGET packages in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 on a new HD, but unfortunately I can’t restore my projects.
I note that the problem is in the restoration of projects by NUGET. I’ve tried it through the package manager and the console.
I also removed VS and then reinstalled, but the problem persists.
Here are some screens with the errors:
Version: 16.10.0
OS: Windows 10
Thank you for your support.

========== Finished ==========

[ApiNuget] The V2 feed at 'https://api.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='netcoreapp3.1'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
[nuget.org] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='netcoreapp3.1'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
[nuget.org] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm='mysql'&targetFramework='netcoreapp3.1'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
[ApiNuget] The V2 feed at 'https://api.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm='mysql'&targetFramework='netcoreapp3.1'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
[Package source] Unable to load the service index for source https://packagesource.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'

[Print1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPzAU.jpg)

[Print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUAiL.jpg)

[Print3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPFpU.jpg)

[Print4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPR45.jpg)

Comment: How are your package sources configured? For nuget.org, this should be https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: Problem solved:
The NUGET polling package was incorrectly configured.
the wrong url was: https://nuget.org
The correct url is: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: Thanks @Klaus Gütter  by solutuion